# Collection field showing undefined when aggregate is used in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to concat two arrays with aggregate. However, output is showing `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'allAddresses')`. And wanted to implement in EJS. How can I achieve that? There is a code below:

```
app.post('/indexReplaced.html', (req, res) => {
  Address.find({}, function(err, item){
    const response = Address.aggregate([
      {
        $group: {
          _id: null,
          addresses: {
            $push: "$addresses"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        $project: {
          allAddresses: {
            $reduce: {
              input: "$addresses",
              initialValue: [],
              in: {
                "$concatArrays": [
                  "$$value",
                  "$$this"
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]);
    const allAddresses = response[0]["allAddresses"];
    res.render("indexCalculated", {
      address: item,
      allAddresses: allAddresses
    })
  })
});
```

P.S: Tried to nest aggregate pipeline into `Address.find()` to render the collection as well. I hope it doesn't affect the pipelane.

Comment: allAddresses - did it return any value?

Comment: Solved, already. Thanks